# On a programmatic view, my button can't be clicked

Tags: uiview, swift

I have a UIView that leads to another UIView. I have userInteraction set to true. My button shows, but the button does not do anything when it is clicked. I added a println statement to make sure that it wasn't just the code I ran in the function. Something is wrong with the view, or how the button and function are connected.

I am using Swift.

**This is my code. It is in snipits, so you won't see the viewDidLoad method:**

```
let initialLaunchController = UIView()
    let teachingScreen = UIView()

        learnToPlayButton.setTitle("Click here to learn how to play.", forState: .Normal)
        learnToPlayButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
        learnToPlayButton.titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 35)
        learnToPlayButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        learnToPlayButton.addTarget(self, action: "LearnToPlayPage:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        learnToPlayButton.frame = CGRectMake(37, 70, 500, 200)
 initialLaunchController.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        teachingScreen.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        initialLaunchController.userInteractionEnabled = true
        teachingScreen.userInteractionEnabled = true

    func LearnToPlayPage(sender: UIButton!) {
        //switch view to actually teach to learn to play

        println("debugging..")

        let imageViewInsideFunc = UIImageView(image: background)
        self.teachingScreen.addSubview(imageViewInsideFunc)
        self.teachingScreen.addSubview(titleToTeachToPlayLabel)
        self.teachingScreen.addSubview(teachToPlayLabel)
        self.teachingScreen.addSubview(sureGetStartedButton)
        self.initialLaunchController.addSubview(teachingScreen)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do have the correct parameter in your `addTarget` method call (`action: "LearnToPlayPage:"`), but the button can't find that method on your view controller subclass because you've nested in inside whatever method is setting up the UIButton. It needs to be defined as a method on your subclass instead:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var learnToPlayButton = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // set up views and button properties    
        learnToPlayButton.addTarget(self, action: "LearnToPlayPage:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        // etc, etc
    }

    func LearnToPlayPage(sender: UIButton!) {
        // switch view to actually teach to learn to play
        println("found LearnToPlayPage(sender: UIButton!)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, the button still does not do anything when clicked.

Comment: Tested and approved. Inner function is out of scope. Making an instance method resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the action parameter with the Selector initializer:

```
learnToPlayButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("LearnToPlayPage"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: Nope, the button still does not do anything when clicked.